# Loop jQuery for each child

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

How do i write a short code that using for(i=1; ... ...); function that allow me to loop through each child and add a different class.

```
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:first-child').addClass('blogpost1');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(2)').addClass('blogpost2');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(3)').addClass('blogpost3');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(4)').addClass('blogpost4');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(5)').addClass('blogpost5');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(6)').addClass('blogpost6');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(7)').addClass('blogpost7');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(8)').addClass('blogpost8');
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table:nth-child(9)').addClass('blogpost9');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
$('#WebPartWPQ3 > table').each(function(i,j){

 $(this).addClass("blogpost"+(i+1));
});
```

Comment: What if `#WebPartWPQ3` has child nodes which aren't tables? Might be better to loop over `$('#WebPartWPQ3').children()` and check if they're a table.